# Zumero DataGrid & Xamarin UWP - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: xamarin, datagrid, xamarin.forms, uwp, zumero-datagrid

I'm attempting to get Zumero DataGrid and Xamarin UWP working together. I have followed all the documentation I can find and unfortunately I'm still getting the following exception thrown in App.g.i.cs:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
  UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
  {
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
      global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  };
#endif
```

Usually I can figure out these things myself with the debugger, but all I have to go on is this:

```
Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

and this:

```
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.TaskExtensions.<>c.<WatchForError>b__2_1(Object e)
at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

Please note that the datagrid works perfectly on Android - just not on my UWP application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add stack trace? Usually if its Zumero error it would have a Error Id or number.

Comment: @Rohit Zumero DataGrid is different from Zumero sync, which doesn't appear to be involved here.

Comment: Its an error on sync right, so it should have something at least in  the stack trace.

Comment: @Rohit I don't believe there is any sync involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Zumero DataGrid has not been ready for UWP, I have tried that but get this exception:

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.dll'

In my experience, this is due to it's lack of Xamarin.Forms UWP renderer in nuget package. Here is a similar issue for other repository: [Xamarin.Forms nuget lacks Windows UWP support (currently only WinRT and SL)](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/120)

Based on the [open source code](https://github.com/zumero/DataGrid/tree/master/), it only support **Windows 8.1/ Windows Phone 8.1/Windows phone 8.0** for Windows Platform

I would recommend you to submit a feature request in their [repository](https://github.com/zumero/DataGrid/tree/master/)

Comment: So its pretty useless then for the 1 BILLION devices out there that support UWP?